# Error while modifying the list view in SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, list-view

We are facing an issue with edit view of the **SharePoint 2013 Lists/Libraries** for particular web application only.

Error is as displayed below:

> Cannot complete this action.
>
> Please try again.
>
> Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation."

We **don't have any correlation ID** while getting an error on page even if we **couldn't able to find any error in ULS viewer or SharePoint Log Viewer**.

Comment: Any error in console/ Network tab?

Comment: Please check the error in Windows Event Viewer. You will get the exact error

Comment: I'm not getting any error even in Event viewer, console/network tab.

Comment: Have you created this list using SP UI or code? as sometimes when you create & delete the view than it creates the problem, if you forget to update the list via code.

Comment: Run the following commands to enable the logs:

a.       New-SPLogFile        [Note: this starts a new ULS log]

b.      Set-SPLogLevel -TraceSeverity VerboseEX        [Note: this sets all logging to super high levels]

Comment: Please check this...https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chaun/2013/11/27/troubleshooting-the-vague-cannot-complete-this-action-owssvr-dll-error/

Comment: Thanks for reply. I've already refer this blog but couldn't helped.

Comment: how many items in this list/library?

Comment: this should be moved to the comment section!

Comment: how many items in this list/library?

Comment: This error comes in all lists/libraries in particular web application.